# How to execute a block only if all previous conditions were false and execute a specific block if one of them was true?

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, or-operator

I'm making a little game in C++, and I'm wondering how to optimize my branching. Look at this code:

```
if (
  isUpPressed ||
  isDownPressed ||
  isLeftPressed ||
  isRightPressed ||
  isSpacePressed
) {
  if (isUpPressed)
    state |= State::MoveUp;
  if (isDownPressed)
    state |= State::MoveDown;
  if (isLeftPressed)
    state |= State::MoveLeft;
  if (isRightPressed)
    state |= State::MoveRight;
  if (isSpacePressed)
    state |= State::Jump);
} else
  state = State::Still;
```

What I want to achieve is: if up, down, left, right or space is pressed, set `state` to the appropriate value. If **none** of these conditions was true, set the state to `State::Still`. My code works, but it feels like I'm doing it wrong. There must be a better way. My question is:
**How to execute a block only if *all* of the specified conditions failed, and execute a block specific to each of these conditions if one or several are true, without using nested `if` and lots of `||` operators as I did?**

Comment: Apart from the redundancy.

Comment: The redundancy is precisely the problem.

Comment: I don't see the redundancy. You have to somehow map events to states at some point if I understand your code correctly.

Comment: Right, but I would like to check if a key is pressed **once and only once**. It shouldn't be necessary to check twice.

Comment: @filsmick I think that it is necessary, since you are asking two different questions ("key pressed" vs "up pressed"). Of course you can use a vector + hashmap, but evenutally you'll end with the same redundancy, only in different place. With the information you gave us (you can use Chnossos' trick if `State::Still == 0`) I doubt you can do better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As taken from bits and pieces in the comments. Something like this perhaps (assuming none of the movement states holds the value 0)

```
State::Value state = State::Value(0);
if (isUpPressed)
    state |= State::MoveUp;
if (isDownPressed)
    state |= State::MoveDown;
if (isLeftPressed)
    state |= State::MoveLeft;
if (isRightPressed)
    state |= State::MoveRight;
if (isSpacePressed)
    state |= State::Jump);

if(state == State::Value(0))
    state = State::Still;

if(isOnFire)
    state |= State::Fire;
```

Alternatively, if you have more blocks of code similar to the movement block, you can create a temp State variable, treat it the same way and merge the temp state and the original state.

Comment: Exactly what I want. If this thing gets more complicated, I'll use temp states as suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do it like that :

```
state = State::Still;

if (isUpPressed)
  state |= State::MoveUp;
if (isDownPressed)
  state |= State::MoveDown;
if (isLeftPressed)
  state |= State::MoveLeft;
if (isRightPressed)
  state |= State::MoveRight;
if (isSpacePressed)
  state |= State::Jump;
```

That way if no key were pressed, `state` is set to `Still`.

If `state` isn't 0 before, meneldal solution could work, that is, use a boolean.

Comment: Brilliant! I should have thought of this. That said, it is perfect for me, but for something a bit more complicated (like displaying a message if none of the keys was pressed), it wouldn't work.

Comment: @filsmick while this may be correct and work for you, it can exhibit different behavior from what you posted originally.

Comment: Well, the code does a different thing. It's at least not clear from OP's question what will happen when you do for example `State::Still | State::MoveUp`. I do agree that that's a good idea though.

Comment: But if a key is pressed, what will be the result when it's bitwise or'ed with `State::Still`?

Comment: Yes there is a problem, I just noticed. The `Still` flag stays in the `state` field, and I have to remove it manually... again, redundancy.

Comment: This will work if `State::Still` is `0` (which would most likely be a good thing anyway).

Comment: I started using bit fields recently so... wouldn't a zero flag be detected all the time? (Ex: `if (state & State::Still)` would return true?)

Comment: @filsmick That's assuming that `State::Still == 0` which you didn't say. Plus it becomes a trick in this particular case, not general solution to the problem.

Comment: Even if Still is 0, it's still different from the original. The original code allows `isUpPressed` on first execution, and `isLeftPressed` on second execution and leave the `state=State::MoveUp | State::MoveLeft`.  This code would leave it as `state=State::MoveLeft`

Comment: You're right about the solution being a trick, but I was replying to @molbdnilo, who suggested using a value of 0 for `State::Still`.

Comment: @imbtfab Well, yeah, that's under assumption that `state` is preserved between executions of the code. I wouldn't assume that though.

Comment: `state` is reinitialized about a thousand times per second. So, let's recap: I give `State::Still` a value of 0 and use the code of this answer?

Comment: @filsmick No, but `state == State::Still` would be true. This only works if `Still` is an "exclusive" state, of course.

Comment: @freakish I agree it's perhaps odd, but if it's not preserved, then what's the initial state of it? It has to be something or the state value is invalid when being or'd. If it's 0 it's simple to get rid of redundant code, or if it's State:Still, we're back to the problem for this solution.

Comment: The problem is, I'm going to add other states, like `Fire`, `Crouch`, and so on. `Still` is only exclusive to movement states.

Comment: @imbtfab `state` is initialized to zero: `State::Value state = State::Value(0);`

Comment: @filsmick Then just do the simple if's and set it to `State:Still` if it's still 0 (meaning no keys was pressed).

Comment: @imbtfab Your solution is very good if I keep my current States, but, as I said, I'm going to add more. The character could very well be `Still` and `Fire` at the same time...

Comment: @filsmick Two options then: 1. Do the movement states as I suggested in my previous comment(setting State:Still if it's still 0), then after that append whatever other states there might be. 2. If the other states needs similar treatment as the move states, use temp states and merge into one in the end.

Comment: @imbtfab `Do the movement states, and set to Still if none`: look at what the original question was :)

Comment: @filsmick I edited to make clear that I was referring as a continiuation to my suggestion in a previous comment ;) This is getting lengthy, perhaps it's clearer if I write it up in an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. Yes, I think you should make an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If State::Still isn't 0 you can set a boolean in every branch. Setting a boolean is a very quick operation so it's probably faster than your first approach. For example

```
bool still=true;

if (isUpPressed)
  still=false, state |= State::MoveUp;
if (isDownPressed)
  still=false, state |= State::MoveDown;
if (isLeftPressed)
  still=false, state |= State::MoveLeft;
if (isRightPressed)
  still=false, state |= State::MoveRight;
if (isSpacePressed)
  still=false, state |= State::Jump;
if(still)
  state=State::Still;
```

There's also probably the nested approach but it's very ugly and probably not better performance wise.